# How to transform the inputs to uppercase while typing in angular8

Tags: angular, uppercase

I need to make an entire application to have uppercase letters while typing. so I tried using in HTML like below.

```
 #input (input)="input.value=$event.target.value.toUpperCase()"
```

And also I went through a directive, which makes inputs into uppercase while typing, but both the things don't allow `ctrl + z`,
when I do `ctrl + z`, then if the input field is empty it must give me empty value, when on edit mode, if there was value already and we try to edit and do `ctrl + z`, then we need to get the value which was stored already.

DEMO:
[DEMO LInk](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-uppercase-lowercase?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Flowercase-input.directive.ts)

DEMO which i tried:
[DEMO Link of what i tried](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2m9nz?file=src/app/app.component.html)
Can anyone help me how to solve this

Comment: You could add css: `text-transform: uppercase;`?

Answer (score 1):

No Need to use Pipe or directived for this.

Simply give a class to input field for example `.myInput`

Now decorate it like following:

```
.myInput {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need bind keyup event for that on angular way. Below is example.

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">
```

Comment: Thanks for response but actually i want ctrl+z operation to work here

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Directive like below code is to trim every input element string like-wise you can use toUpperCase():

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="number"], textarea, input[type="password"]',
  providers: [NgModel]
})
export class StringTrimDirective {
  @Output() ngModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter()

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private model: NgModel) {
    // To know trim is applied or not. For Testing
    //el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }

  @HostListener('change') onInputChange3() {
    // no-trim attribute on element will skip the triming.
    if (!this.el.nativeElement.noTrim) {
      const value = this.el.nativeElement.value.trim();
      this.model.viewModel = value; 
      this.ngModelChange.emit(value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, i am using reactive forms, can this be used there?

Comment: can you please edit your answer in this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g67fwz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I have edited you code and added a new Input field of Name.. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  control: FormControl;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.control = new FormControl();

    this.control.valueChanges
    .pipe(
        tap((value) => console.log(value)),
        tap((value: string) => this.control.setValue(value.toUpperCase(), {emitEvent: false})
      )
    )
    .subscribe()
  }
}
```

component.html

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="control">
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-5ie7aw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)